# Limiting editing access and setting up permissions so users can create new records but cant see the whole sheet

Tags: permissions, excel, sharing, excel-online

I am hoping that excel online can become a new system for entering in daily time for our company. id like to set it up so that our field crews can enter in their daily time on an excel online sheet but I would like to limit access so that they can only create new records and they would not be able to see all the information from previous records. is this even possible? if so any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support row level permissions. You could create a list and a flow that writes records to a different destination, such as a different list or an Excel spreadsheet, and which also deletes the original row submitted to the list.

Or, lists support having permissions so that users only see their own records, which might also meet your needs.